# Is there any reach weapon with 1d10 damage or more?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Are there any reach weapons for humanoid medium characters with over 1d8 or 2d4 damage? I would prefer official weapons and not third-party releases. If it is a weapon of non-official source, please let it be somewhat legitimate as a weapon, not the kind that would be unusable in real life.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Glaive (PH p117) 2Hand 1d10 20 / x3 — S 8 gp 10 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Polearm
>
> Naginata (DR331 p24) 2Hand 1d10 20 / x3 — S 10 gp 15 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Polearm
>
> Voulge (DR331 p24) 2Hand 1d10 20 / x3 — S 10 gp 14 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Polearm
>
> Greatspear (CWar p156) (CAdv p116)+ 2Hand 2d6 20 / x3 10’ P 25 gp 9 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Polearm Shared Focus (Longspear)
>
> Lochaber Axe (DR331 p24) 2Hand 1d10 20 / x3 — S 18 gp 15 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Trip, Polearm
>
> Longaxe
>   (CAdv p115) 2Hand 1d12 20 / x3 — S 35 gp 15 lbs 5 10 A proficient user with Power Attack that shifts at least 3 points to damage can use the Longaxe as Reach 10’ for the whole round Shared Focus (Greataxe)
>
> Longspear, Microlith Barbed (DR331 p84) 2Hand 1d10 20 / x3 — P 5 gp 9 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’
>
> Pincer Staff (Und p64) 2Hand 1d10 20 / x2 — B 20 gp 15 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Grapple
>
> Poleaxe, Heavy (CWar p156) (CAdv p116)+ 2Hand 2d6 20 / x3 — P or S 20 gp 15 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Vs. Charge, Polearm Shared Focus (Halberd)
>
> Sharrash, Talenta (Eb p120)(EbEratta)+ 2Hand 1d10 19-20 / x2 — S 18 gp 10 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, Trip, Polearm
>
> Sugliin (Frost p76) 2Hand 2d8 20 / x2 — S & P 35 gp 20 lbs 10 10 Reach 10’ Single attack requires a Full Round Action unless you also have Feat: Sugliin Mastery.
>
> Warpike, Dwarven (RoS p155)(DR331 p24) 2Hand 2d6 20 / x3 — P or S 45 gp 15 lbs 5 10 Reach 10’, vs. Charge, Trip, Polearm

*Source: D20 Lists - DnD3.5Index-Equipment*

**Edit:**
Link provided by Cthos:
http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#reachWeapons

Comment: By 5 Seconds! :)

Comment: +1. Added your link to the post! I thought it was handy.